# HTML 5 Data attributes without value in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

How do I do this in HAML when i have HTML 5 Data attributes without value

```
<p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#mypanel">Panel</a></p>
```

I have done this, but HAML raises an error

```
%p{ class: "title", data: { section: {:title}}}= link_to "Panel", "#mypanel"
```

Thanks

Comment: How about a blank string? `data: { section: { title: "" } }`. Is `data-section-title` actually different than `data-section-title=""`?

Comment: The spec doesn't seem to say anything about using custom data attributes in the boolean way. My belief is that would be invalid. In the pure HTML way, what value does the dataset contain for such an attribute? You could try {:title => nil}, or {:title => true}.

Comment: @KyleTruscott i havent tried it. Actually, I got a HTML template based on Zurb Foundation from my designer with that HTML 5 data attributes. The template works well. and i want to convert my template to HAML. I'm afraid if your trick will cause errors. I think it is different than data-section-title=""

Comment: @Nate yap, i dont find any clues in HAML's reference page

Comment: Yeah, based on that question @BenjaminSinclaire referenced, you may be able to use `{ title: true }`

Comment: `{:title}` isn't a valid hash. You can't have a hash with an element, they're made out of keys and values.

Comment: yess, its amazingly works using { title: true } . Thanks alot everyone :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just finished writing this out for a project I'm working on. I couldn't find it within the foundation docs.

```
.large-12.columns
.section-container.auto{:data => {'section' => true}} 
    %section
        %p.title{:data => {'section-title' => true}} 
            %a{:href=>"#panel1" } Section 1
        .content{:data => {'section-content' => true}}  
            %p Content of section 1
    %section
        %p.title{:data => {'section-title' => true}}
            %a{:href=>"#panel2" } Section 2
        .content{:data => {'section-content' => true}}  
            %p Content of section 2
```

Comment: It's easier to read it this way:
`%tag{'data-foo-bar' => true}`

Comment: The given answer works, but it produces an HTML attribute with value. If you want the attribute only to be output on HTML, without value, you can use the HTML-style attributes syntax of HAML ([here the reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html)): `%p(data-section-title){ class: "title" }= link_to "Panel", "#mypanel"`